# How to count the number of elements on the first row of their parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

My question is, is there a way maybe in JavaScript that I can determine how many child elements are going to fit across the first row of a parent element?  I would then multiply that by a fixed number of rows and query up that many at a time.

To better understand what is going on, if I query for 20 items and the page size is such that I can fit 6 elements per row, I will be left with two blank spaces on the last row.  I would like to query for just enough so that there are no empty cells on the last row.

The page is here:  http://www.spacerock.com/dvds.php

I'm trying to figure out a whiz-bang way to do this dynamically and massage the number by the page size.

Comment: That's not technically "responsive", that's just "fluid". "responsive" would be if you had breakpoints to adjust styles. But anyway, surely it's just a case of `containerWidth / itemWidth`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I understand you better now.  Try this code out.  Run it as is and observe the count, then go to full-screen mode and run it again.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    function countFirstRowItems(parentSelector, childSelector){
        var count = 0, theTop = undefined;
        $(parentSelector + " > " + childSelector).each(function(){
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
            if(theTop === undefined){
                theTop = thisTop;
            }
            if(thisTop != theTop){
                return false;
            }
            count++;
        });
        return count;
    }
    
    $('#btnCount').click(function(){
        $('#spnCount').html(
            countFirstRowItems('.outer', '.item')
        );
    });

    $('#spnCount').html(
        countFirstRowItems('.outer', '.item')
    );
    
});
```

```css
.outer{
  padding:.5em;
  margin:.5em;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
}
.item{
  margin:.5em;
  height:150px;
  width:100px;
  border:solid 1px #ddd;
  float:left;
  background-color:#fdfafa;
}
.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnCount">Count items on first row</button>
<span id="spnCount">?</span>
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing that I am doing behind the scenes is pagination. There is a query that brings up 20 at a time but that number might change... according to the width.  They are floating left and when the viewport is narrower, not as many will show in a row.  What I'm trying to do is dynamically make those rows even - each row will have the same number of items (cells) in it.  I have to figure out a way to change my offset I am querying up from the database - dynamically - based on the page width of how many are possible to show in even rows.  Does that clarify?

Comment: So you don't want the last row to have empty spaces?

Comment: Right.  No empty spaces.

Comment: If I can find a way for it to count the first row of the class .moviecell, then I could make an ajax call to make it bring up a number from the db multiplied by how many are in that first row x 4 for instance.

Comment: Check out my new answer

Comment: Okay I got the counting to occur but the plot thickens - since the initial page load relies upon my offset limits from the db (via php script), how can I get that number on page load?  Exactly.  I can't....not sure the best way to handle this - but it's a wonderful puzzle for me to figure out...

Comment: There really isn't a reliable way to get this number before the DOM is loaded, but you can call the `countFirstRowItems()` in the `$(document).ready()` method, which is about as early as you are going to get an accurate measurement.  I updated my example code to do this.  You could use AJAX to query the database after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: If you find it helpful, don't forget to upvote and/or mark as answer.